# Mokken Scaling "cross loaded" items

Tags: item-response-theory

I have a scale that I am testing using Mokken scaling. I also ran an EFA and used multidimensional scaling. The results for EFA and MDS overlapp substantially, and when I use Mokken scaling on these items, I get high scalability and reliability. However, when I run the Mokken scaling on the full scale, I get 6 clusters which overlap substantially. Here is an example of the first two clusters:

```
   Cluster 1: RA1, RA2, RA3, COMP1, COMP2, OBS1, OBS2, OBS3, OBS4, JOY1, JOY2, PRI1, PRI2, PRI3

   Cluster 2: RA3,CA2, CA3, COMP1, COMP2, COMP3, TRI2, OBS1, OBS2, OBS3, OBS4, PRI1, PRI2, PRI3, JOY1, JOY2
```

Each has strong scalability and reliability. Does this suggest that the scale can be used unidimensionally? What do "cross loaded" items in mokken scaling indicate?

Comment: When you say "The results for EFA and MDS overlapp substantially, and when I use Mokken scaling on these items, I get high scalability and reliability" do you mean that you used EFA to identify factors and then applied the Mokken scaling to the items that load on a single factor?

Comment: Great question. I'm sorry for not being clear. No, I ran the mokken scaling on the full set, hoping to confirm the EFA. My sample is small and likely unstable; we are working on preliminary data for a next study but trying to understand the measure a bit more. No strong conclusions...

Comment: I used an automated search

Comment: So is the Mokken scaling you refer to in the second sentence the same one that you refer to in the third sentence? I read that as two separate analyses you conducted

Comment: I am very sorry for not being clear. 
I have one set of items that is theorized to make up 6 subscales. I did an EFA and the factor somewhat loaded onto the theorized scales, but not completely. I then did MDS and the results showed similar clusters to the EFA.  Then, on the same data, I ran Mokken scaling. The results  of mokken are vastly different and I'm strugging to interpret. 

My first run was using alt code, which I think may have been in error. I may have solved my problem by using aisp in  mokken package. The results differ , but instability due to sample size may be to blame.

Comment: This may or may not be the issue in your case, but in my (limited) experience with Mokken scaling, I've found that the cutoff that you set during the search process can have an effect on the scales that are reported. For example, whether or not the results overlap with the results of an EFA will depend on the cutoff chosen.